# Not able to filter all running journeys via Marketing cloud API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder

I am trying to view all journeys with Published status(if current version is draft then previous published version) but not able to do so as list of all journeys is returned.

```
curl -X GET \
  https://www.exacttargetapis.com/interaction/v1/interactions \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer ZtvZHAqgTAUXlA8wkYYj0tZ0' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'status: Published'
```

Below is the output:

```
{
    "count": 2,
    "page": 1,
    "pageSize": 50,
    "links": {},
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "883efb08-9c61-45c2-8d2c-94c117b2433b",
            "key": "3e8526cb-c118-ee11-0312-0defa176cf4f",
            "name": "Barneys Lapsed",
            "lastPublishedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "description": "",
            "version": 1,
            "workflowApiVersion": 1,
            "createdDate": "2018-05-01T14:28:30.333",
            "modifiedDate": "2018-05-01T14:28:30.363",
            "goals": [],
            "exits": [],
            "stats": {
                "currentPopulation": 0,
                "cumulativePopulation": 0,
                "metGoal": 0,
                "metExitCriteria": 0,
                "goalPerformance": 0
            },
            "entryMode": "NotSet",
            "defaults": {
                "properties": {
                    "analyticsTracking": {
                        "enabled": false,
                        "analyticsType": "google",
                        "urlDomainsToTrack": []
                    }
                }
            },
            "metaData": {},
            "executionMode": "Production",
            "categoryId": 43612,
            "status": "Draft",
            "definitionId": "883efb08-9c61-45c2-8d2c-94c117b2433b"
        },
        {
            "id": "846eb7fb-2d86-42da-bd9a-cde69c491e04",
            "key": "2f0b3fb9-9581-ac3c-69ec-6c9c2f9302ef",
            "name": "RC Test 1",
            "lastPublishedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "description": "",
            "version": 1,
            "workflowApiVersion": 1,
            "createdDate": "2018-05-07T11:40:45.867",
            "modifiedDate": "2018-05-07T11:40:45.883",
            "goals": [],
            "exits": [],
            "stats": {
                "currentPopulation": 0,
                "cumulativePopulation": 0,
                "metGoal": 0,
                "metExitCriteria": 0,
                "goalPerformance": 0
            },
            "entryMode": "NotSet",
            "defaults": {
                "properties": {
                    "analyticsTracking": {
                        "enabled": false,
                        "analyticsType": "google",
                        "urlDomainsToTrack": []
                    }
                }
            },
            "metaData": {},
            "executionMode": "Production",
            "categoryId": 43612,
            "status": "Published",
            "definitionId": "846eb7fb-2d86-42da-bd9a-cde69c491e04"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work. Sorry I'm not familiar with the CURL GET so I can't say exactly where you're going wrong, but if you hit the URL:

https://www.exacttargetapis.com/interaction/v1/interactions?status=published

It should filter accordingly. There is no apostrophe or any other punctuation in the URL.

Comment: Thanks @AnonWonderer, it worked for me in url string.

Answer (score 1):

@Zoso7 use like this

```
Host: https://www.exacttargetapis.com/interaction/v1/interactions
Method:GET 
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

for me iam getting all journeys @Zoso7

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, actually I am getting all the journeys, but not able to filter out the running ones. Basically `status: Published` parameter is not working for me.